# BMDCapture (bmdtools) capture with Ultrastudio Mini recorder results is color problems

Tags: terminal, osx-yosemite, avconv

I'm trying to get a Blackmagic Ultrastudio Mini Recorder to stream via avconv to HLS. To test, it's hooked up to an AppleTV and this is the command I'm using:

```
./bmdcapture -m 14 -C 0 -F nut -f pipe:1 | avconv -vsync passthrough -y -i - -vcodec copy -pix_fmt yuyv422 -strict experimental -f hls -hls_list_size 999 +live -strict experimental out.m3u8
```

However, the colors are all messed up; suggesting the color format is set incorrectly. The input format is 1280x720 @ 59.94 FPS (which is correct) and I've set the format to yuyv422 (though nothing else I've set this to has fixed the error).

[image: screenshot 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

The Mini Recorder shoots at 10 bits rather than 8 (which I assumed considering Adobe's live encoder said it would be 8).

Here is the fixed code:

```
./bmdcapture -m 14 -p yuv10 -C 0 -F nut -f pipe:1 | avconv -vsync passthrough -y -i - -vcodec copy -pix_fmt uyvy422 -strict experimental -f hls -hls_list_size 999 +live -strict experimental out.m3u8
```